# GoogleMobileAds The type or namespace name 'Build' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I've imported the GoogleMobileAds into my Unity project and was able to make it all work fine in unity. however when i try to create an Android build i keep getting errors of editor code. I've found out that everything in an Editor folder should be considered editor code and should be skipped when creating other builds. however this does not seem to work.

```
Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Editor\BuildPreProcessor.cs(5,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Build' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

i get mutiple of these errors. all related to GoogleMobileAds.

Some interesting info:

- i'm using Unity 2021.3.30f1
- the GoogleMobileAds is the latest one
- I've noticed that the GoogleMobileAds is in a different project for the editor stuff.
  [image: project picture]

Answer (score 0):

Seems i had an old version of GoogleMobileAds messing with the new one. deleting everything related to it and reimporting the package fixed it.